# IQueryable/Linq Orderby Fail: Sorts only a limited number of records

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, sql-order-by, iqueryable

I have a an application that handles hundreds of records at a time and I use the following code to order the query but it will sort and order only a limited number of records.

```
switch (sortOrder)
{
case "created":
    folders = (from f in folders orderby f.created_date ascending select f);

    //folders = folders.OrderBy(f => f.created_date.Value.Year)
    //                .ThenBy(f => f.created_date.Value.Month)
    //                .ThenBy(f => f.created_date.Value.Day);
    break;
case "created_desc":
    folders = (from f in folders orderby f.created_date descending select f);

    //folders = folders.OrderByDescending(f => f.created_date.Value.Year)
    //                    .ThenByDescending(f => f.created_date.Value.Month)
    //                    .ThenByDescending(f => f.created_date.Value.Day);
    break;
default:
    folders = folders.OrderBy(f => f.folder_number);
    break;
}
```

Additionally, when I try to sort it multiple times: ascending, descending then ascending again, it won't sort past the first ascending sort. If that makes sense. So it'll sort fine for the first 20 or so records, but then when you continue to scroll down, you can see that all of the records were not sorted properly. I've tried IQueryable and Linq and both produces the same results.

[image: Sort by Create Date img1]

[image: Sort by Create Date img2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are applying your sorting on top of the previous Linq query, since you are overwriting your `folders` variable every time. Instead, you should keep `folders` as an unsorted data source and keep sorted results separately, without overwriting `folders`.

So instead of this:

```
folders = (from f in folders ...
```

You should do this:

```
var sortedFolders = (from f in folders ...
```

Comment: Absolutely fantastic! This has been driving me nuts on and off for the past couple of weeks. Thanks!!